# ¿Como hacer procesos en segundo plano con python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Quiero realizar procesos en segundo plano con python 3.x, por ejemplo.:

```py
    import os
    hola = ["hola", "HOLA"]

    def repetir_hola():
        for palabra in hola:
            print(palabra)
            os.system("cls") #esto limpia tu pantalla

    def escribir():
        while True: #Esto hace que esto se ejecute de forma infinita
            archivo = open("archivo.txt", "w") #Esto abre una archivo txt en tu 
                                               #directorio actual
            archivo.write("Estoy escribiendo en un archivo") #Esto escribe en tu archivo
```

Como podría hacer para que se ejecutase los dos bucles a la vez, es decir, que escribiera en el archivo "Estoy escribiendo en un archivo" y a la vez nos muestre el pantalla la palabra "hola" y "Hola"

Answer (score -2):

Puedes utilizar un método llamado Threading. Es un módulo de Python para hacer subprocesos y ejecutar bucles en segundo plano. [Aquí una guía](https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/multiprocesamiento-en-python-threads-a-fondo-introduccion) Espero que esto te resuelva tu problema!